# check if a register value is even/odd in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I tried to do the following:

```
                        # with $s6 holding i+j
andi $s7, $s6, 0x1      # (i + j) & 1 (to check if it's even)
if: bneq $s7, $zero, else
```

however it generates an error... am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does the else tag exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps your assembler doesn't like `0x1` integers?

```
andi $s7, $s6, 1
bnez $s7, odd         # branch if not-equal to Zero.
```

Or if your assembler doesn't like ABI names for registers, use register numbers?

```
andi $23, $22, 1      # $22=$s6  and   $23=$s7
```

If you use MARS or SPIM Simulator, or clang or other normal MIPS assemblers,
`andi $s7, $s6, 0x1` assembles just fine.

---

Note `andi` doesn't add anything, so the `i+j` comment doesn't match

> **andi Rdest, Rsrc1, Imm**
>  Put the logical
> AND of the integers from register
> Rsrc1 And Imm into register Rdest.

Comment: Yes, it could be that your simulator doesnt support it.

Answer (score 1):

bneq does not exist.

Use

```
bne $s7,$zero,else
```

Post edit:

Heres a working example

```
  #include<mips/regdef>
    ...
    andi    t1,t1,0x1
```

Please add any error msg!

Comment: yes, I changed that as well but still it doesn't work... problem is at andi

Comment: @aherlambang - What assembler are you using?  `andi $s7, $s6, 0x1` assembles in MARS or `clang -target mips`, and is the same instruction as `andi $s7, $s6, 1` in the answer you accepted.  `bneq` *isn't* valid, though.

Answer (score 0):

Following your question title, I thought this answer could be as useful to someone else as it was for me:

Since, for a binary value, if it ends with 0, it's even, if it ends with 1, it's odd. So, you basically need to get the first bit of a number with shift logical instructions like bellow.

```
sll $t0, $s0, 0x1F      
srl $s1, $t0, 0x1F
```

- s0 contains the value to be validated
- t0 intermediates the shift operations
- s1 has the final result (0 for even, 1 for odd)
- Since each register has a value of 32 bits and we need just the first one, we shift the others 31 (0x1F) bits

Comment: `reg & 1` is a more efficient way to isolate the low bit than `(reg << 31) >> 31`.  This works but has zero advantage over the other answers.  If you want to branch on it, you could just do the left shift and `bltz $t0, odd` since you shifted the low bit into the sign bit.